# Java invoke com.apple.loginitems

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to add my Java Application to the "Login Items" preferences pane that appears in OSX. This pane is visible if you go to System Preferences --> Accounts, and click on your account name. You should then see a "Login Items" of programs that will automatically open when you log in.

I know I can add my program using launchd, or LaunchServices, but I had a few users ask if it could display inside the "Login Items" window. In order to do this, I believe I need to modify com.apple.loginitems.plist, but the file is written in binary so it can't be readily accessed. I've looked at it using

```
defaults read com.apple.loginitems
```

and I've tried writing to it using

```
defaults write com.apple.loginitems key value
```

but it looks like the loginitems plist is quite complex and has a weird structure. I'm wondering if there's any proper way to do this using Java. I believe there used to be a Cocoa Java extension that let you do this, but I don't think that's possible anymore in Snow Leopard.

Hopefully someone can give me a hand here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ended up writing a (very) short Cocoa console application in XCode using http://github.com/carpeaqua/Shared-File-List-Example/blob/master/Controller.m as an example